# How to search / filter your own questions?

Tags: support, search

Is there an easy way where you can perform a search of your own questions or apply a filter (Say I only want to list the questions that has a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) tag on it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Go to [Advance Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search). You will get more tips there.

[user:me is:question [Regex]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20is:question%20%5BRegex%5D)
`user:me` is better option if you want to search your own questions.

If you want to search other user's question you can use it with `user:UserId` like this:

[user:1455529 is:question [Regex]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1455529%20is:question%20%5BRegex%5D)

Here 1455529 is your `UserId`. Put other user's `UserId` to search their questions.

`is:question` limits the search to questions only.

Comment: Orgasmic feature.

Comment: `user:me` is a shortcut you can use so you don't have to figure out your user ID number on every site.

Comment: @AlEverett Ahh. forgot that. :)

Comment: this search option is also automatically put into the search bar when you're on your profile pages

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes. Not only on own profile page but also on any user's profile page.