# How can I find unanswered questions of interest, that I have not yet answered?

Tags: feature-request, search

I can search for `is:question intags:mine hasaccepted:no` and add other criteria as I wish, but there's no way to express 'that have no answer by me'.

That seems like a useful addition to me, since if I'm looking for questions to answer, I have no use to questions I've already written an answer for.

Is there any way of doing this, short of the Data Explorer (which of course lags behind the main sites)?

Comment: I think it is. I _did_ search, but missed that one.

Comment: I hoped `-user:me` would work for you but after testing that was not true. In the search to confirm my findings I stumbled on the duplicate...